# Calling java API from c/c++ in Android

Tags: java, android, c++, c, java-native-interface

I am trying to call a java API from c/c++. I wrote a code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#incldue <jni.h>
int main()
{

   JavaVM *vm;
   JNIEnv *env;
   JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
   vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
   vm_args.nOptions = 0;
   vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 1;

    // Construct a VM
    jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, &env, &vm_args);

    jclass cls = env->FindClass("Classname");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "methodname", "(I)V");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, 100);

     /* We are done. */
    vm->DestroyJavaVM();
}
```

On runtime it throws an error like **Failed to create JniInvocation instance before using JNI invocation API**
Any suggestion ?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try checking the call to `JNI_CreateJavaVM` for errors.

Comment: I suspect that the error occurs during the call to `JNI_CreateJavaVM`. In Android at least, there's a [check in that function](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libnativehelper/+/idea133/JniInvocation.cpp) to see if a required `JniInvocation` object has been created. The OP didn't specify which VM (s)he's targetting, though.

Comment: I think , the error is in that `JNI_CreateJavaVM ` function .But how do we remove it ?

Comment: @Michael , I've seen that code , But not able to get anything about how to remove it .

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're trying to do, but you can find the source code for the old dalvik command-line utility here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/jb-mr2-release/dalvikvm/Main.cpp . You have [android] tagged; are you trying to run this on desktop or on an Android device? What VM are you linked against?

Comment: @fadden i'm trying to run it on an android device.